# Github + Ajax call to access file content in JSON format

Tags: jquery, json, github

In my project I am trying to access one file from github in the form of JSON as input for ajax function. But I am getting this error. I am not able to resolve it.

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://jsfiddle.net/jN3rs/5/.
>   This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or
>   enabling CORS.

Jquery Call :

```
var url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/test/Utility/ScheduleTest.json";
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',  //use jsonp data type in order to perform cross domain ajax
    crossDomain: true,
    url: url,
    success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       alert(responseData);
       json_value = responseData;
    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert('POST failed.');
    }
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jN3rs/5/)

Answer (score 2):

That URL is not giving back the correct content type on purpose so that you don't host from it (it returns a content-type of text/plain for all responses).  Try using http://rawgit.com.

Edit: You may have to do more to get the correct mime-type back from this URL.  It looks like you're looking for text/javascript so maybe you could use an extension of .js?

Comment: Yes Got it by changing the content-type from JSON to Text, I got the values. Only processing is remaining... Thanks buddy

Comment: But I hv problem here, my file will change in every 5 minutes then it will not give that flexibility. It will blacklist my URL if hits increases. Is there any alternative for this...

Comment: You could potentially set up an nginx instance or something to do a reverse proxy across.  I believe that's basically what rawgit.com is doing.  It may be easier to set up a server with an API for the information.